# How to save multiple image files to dropbox using dropbox saver api?

Tags: ajax, dropbox, dropbox-api, dropbox-php

I am trying to save multiple images to dropbox using dropbox saver api but my code doesnt save the images and i dont get any error and no confirmation .(**dropbox saver window pops up and click save and it closes but no confirmation!**) could any one tell me how to fix this problem ?

**Note:** I am able to save one image using this function call:

```
Dropbox.save('<?PHP  echo $imagePath1_Value; ?>', 'image1.jpg', options);
```

full code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.dropbox.com/static/api/2/dropins.js" id="dropboxjs" data-app-key="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"></script>
<script>

function saver(){

var options = { 

files: [
        // You can specify up to 100 files.
        // ...
        {'url': '<?PHP  echo $imagePath1_Value; ?>', 'filename': '1.jpg'},
        {'url': '<?PHP  echo $imagePath2_Value; ?>', 'filename': '2.jpg'},
        {'url': '<?PHP  echo $imagePath3_Value; ?>', 'filename': '3.jpg'},

    ],

    // Success is called once all files have been successfully added to the user's
    // Dropbox, although they may not have synced to the user's devices yet.
    success: function () {
        // Indicate to the user that the files have been saved.
        alert("Success! Files saved to your Dropbox.");
    },

    // Progress is called periodically to update the application on the progress
    // of the user's downloads. The value passed to this callback is a float
    // between 0 and 1. The progress callback is guaranteed to be called at least
    // once with the value 1.
    progress: function (progress) {},

    // Cancel is called if the user presses the Cancel button or closes the Saver.
    cancel: function () {},

    // Error is called in the event of an unexpected response from the server
    // hosting the files, such as not being able to find a file. This callback is
    // also called if there is an error on Dropbox or if the user is over quota.
    error: function (errorMessage) {}

};

Dropbox.save(options);
};
</script>
<button onclick="saver()">save(Multiple images)</button>
```

Comment: This code looks largely okay. Is your error callback being called? Can you log the value of `errorMessage`?

Comment: Thanks for reply .how i can check if error callback being called and how to log the value of error Message? no error shows in page after i click save on saver window!

Comment: Just add code to the error handler. E.g. `error: function (errorMessage) { alert("ERROR: " + errorMessage); }`

Comment: Thanks it helped me fix the problem . Problem was two files were named same! Is there away that i place file urls in dynamic array and use that array call saver function ?